# Using Encryption (Hash Algorithm) On Variables

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, hash

Currently, I am encrypting data entering a database utilizing code I found on the web and as an introduction to the topic. My question, here, stems from two WikiHow articles (and is particular to these articles): one on [login](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) encryption; the other on [session security](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL). Both articles appear quite good; however, there is one critical difference between the two: the former states that a JavaScript definition of the utilized hasing algorithm (`$password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt)` is required for the PHP, itself to work.

Even with the inclusion of the PHP `hash()` method (found in both articles), the writer of the first states that the `'sha512'` encryption must itself be *defined* externally using another language (the writer suggests JavaScript).

From reading the PHP documentation, my impression was that `hash()` was able to handle a series of pre-defined hashing algorithms recognized by an identifier, e.g. `whirpool`, `sha512`, etc. These PHP identifiers can be grabbed via `hash_algos()` (or you can just read the documentation).

Am I wrong in thinking that the external definition of the particular pre-defined hash algorithm is unnecessary?

Comment: Hashing in Javascript is only really an attempt to protect the password before transmission over the unsecure HTTP protocol. Passwords should really only be sent over HTTPS anyway.

Comment: @Jonathon that's what I was thinking. So, really, the only reason JavaScript would be needed would be if the transfer were unsecure?

Comment: A bit ranting, but he makes some fair points > http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no need for using javascript to hash a string.

Personally, i'd rather use bcrypt than sha512, but it's fine, it's not really a weak algorithm.

```
$password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt)
```

This is a good way to hash your passwords, and if you feel like going full throttle, you can look up PBKDF2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm